# update spatial data from excel to ms-sql server 2008

Tags: mapinfo, excel, sql-server

I have 1000's of data with 50's of column. It is point data. The data 
is in MS-SQL server.Now each day I need to load 100's of data similar 
in structure. How can I achieve it ? I tried to append table but it 
was lengthy task. I need to change column type since mapinfo does not 
properly recognize every field.Also when I change the column it cannot 
convert some type.
**`Is it possible or has anybody done this can of stuff! Is there any solution to this pain?`** 
I was thinking of doing direct update from excel but before I get 
started I was wondering advice from experts!!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I had similar problem a year or so ago. I tried with SSIS but I had big problems with geometry data type. I could not get it to work at that time. So solution for me was to program a little python script that would parse csv file that I prepared in Excel. Only thing that you need is [Python](http://www.python.org/download/) and [pymssql](http://www.lfd.uci.edu/~gohlke/pythonlibs/#pymssql) module (links refer to Windows OS) and a little programing knowledge. This is part from that script, maybe it will help you.

```
import pymssql
import sys

try:
    conn_mssql = pymssql.connect(host='10.100.0.108:3232', user='sa', password='pass123', database='address');
    conn_mssql.autocommit('ON');
    cur_mssql = conn_mssql.cursor()
except:
    print "I am unable to connect to the database"


myfile = open('file_to_import.csv', 'r')
for line in myfile.readlines():
    lista = line.replace("\n", "").split(';')

    cur_mssql.execute("INSERT INTO kbr(street_id,name,number,the_geom) VALUES (" + lista[0] + ",'" + lista[1] + "','" + lista[2] + "',geometry::STGeomFromText('POINT(" + lista[3] + " " + lista[4] + ")',0));")

myfile.close()
conn_mssql.close()
```

Comment: Thanks you for reply :)!So you are creating point from the lat-lon column of csv file Am I right?

Comment: No problem. I'm doing some coordinate systems conversion with proj4 module before inserting, but you can insert lat-lon without any problem. Ideally should be if you insert as geography::STGeomFromText instead of geometry::STGeomFromText if you are using log-lat but it can be a problem for some applications because most of them only read geometry data type.

Answer (score 1):

Depending on how much programming you want to do [GeoTools](http://geotools.org) may be able to help. It has an [Excel datastore](http://docs.geotools.org/latest/userguide/library/data/excel.html) and an [SQLServer datastore](http://docs.geotools.org/latest/userguide/library/jdbc/sqlserver.html) so you should be able to read in your Excel file and write the features to SQLServer reasonably easily. Most of the code you'll need can be found in the [CSV2SHP tutorial](http://docs.geotools.org/latest/userguide/tutorial/feature/csv2shp.html).

Comment: Thanks I read there are lot of thing to be learned.Thank you very much! I would report my solution :) .

Answer (score 1):

You could have a look at automating it with SSIS packages.  They can be a bit funny about Geometry and Geography datatypes, but you can get round that by executing SQL statement at the various steps.

Comment: Thanks but http://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/16518/update-spatial-data-from-excel-to-ms-sql-server-2008/16553#16553 says it has some issues

Answer (score 1):

Install FME Desktop Trial and it's very easy to translate MapInfo to Sql Server or Excel to Sql Server. No development !!

Comment: I want a script running so that any changes in the excel would update database or insert!

Comment: Configuration of writer : Update or Insert http://docs.safe.com/fme/reader_writerPDF/xls_ado.pdf